Where is the Systemd ordering cycle occurring?
I have to Systemd units a service and a socket. The desired behavior is that when I start the socket the service will start first followed by the socket and when either is taken down they should both go down. The service binds to the socket before the socket unit starts which is why I have it as a notify service so it doesn't report as started until it has the bind on the socket.
Here are the files for the two Units.
#rustyvxcan.service
[Unit]
Description=Docker VXCAN plugin Service
#PartOf=rustyvxcan.socket
    
Before=docker.service
After=network.target
    
[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /run/docker/plugins
ExecStart=/home/braedon/.cargo/bin/rustycan4docker
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

#rustyvxcan.socket
[Unit]
Description=A network plugin for vxcan
Before=docker.service
AssertPathExists=/run/docker/plugins
Requires=rustyvxcan.service
After=rustyvxcan.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/docker/plugins/rustyvxcan.sock
RemoveOnStop=True

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

The error message is as follows.
Sep 19 16:50:38 localhost systemd[1]: rustyvxcan.service: Found ordering cycle on rustyvxcan.socket/start
Sep 19 16:50:38 localhost systemd[1]: rustyvxcan.service: Found dependency on rustyvxcan.service/start
Sep 19 16:50:38 localhost systemd[1]: rustyvxcan.service: Unable to break cycle starting with rustyvxcan.service/start
Sep 19 16:55:09 localhost systemd[1]: rustyvxcan.socket: Found ordering cycle on rustyvxcan.service/start
Sep 19 16:55:09 localhost systemd[1]: rustyvxcan.socket: Found dependency on rustyvxcan.socket/start
Sep 19 16:55:09 localhost systemd[1]: rustyvxcan.socket: Unable to break cycle starting with rustyvxcan.socket/start

From the resources I seem it means the cycle is only happening with these two files and I can clear the error by removing the After line from the .socket file but then they boot simultaneously and the executable for the service fails. I could probably resolve this simply by adding a sleep to the socket however I don't see enough dependency information here to cause a cycle.
I have tried clearing out /{lib,etc}/systemd/system of the service and socket file and reinstalling the ones pasted here just to make sure older versions weren't running, and of course running systemctl daemon-reload regularly while modifying it. But I cant seem to figure out why specifying after breaks the dependency graph even after stripping out dependencies from the service file.
Where is the loop happening that I am missing?

"The service binds to the socket before the socket unit starts" ... wait, what? With systemd socket/service pairs, systemd creates the socket and passes it to the service. If the service is making its own socket then there's no point to a socket unit.

...not only is there no point to a socket unit, it's actively harmful because the systemd-created one will "eat" the 1st connection attempt.

Then maybe I'm running into a different issue because if I run the socket first. The code I am writing throws an error that the socket address is already in use if the socket launches first. This may be the docker process binding to the socket though so Ill do some testing with it outside of the docker plugin folder.
Would this cycle issue be part of the default behavior of a socket unit to prevent the usage you described?

It is the case where I was handling it wrong in the binary which is why my issue was occurring. I'm still not sure where the cycle was occurring but I guess it doesn't matter since I was using the features incorrectly.


The code I am writing throws an error that the socket address is already in use if the socket launches first.

This sounds like you're trying to call bind() yourself.  The systemd socket will actually do that for you.  This is why your socket is failing to bind when you force the service to start first.
In the case of ListenStream= (a TCP connection), systemd will call socket(), bind(), and listen() for you.
If you have Accept=no (default), when data is received on the socket, systemd will start your process and pass that socket's FD to you in environment variable $LISTEN_FDS (see sd_listen_fds(3) for details). This FD is the file-descriptor of the listening socket.  You need to call accept() to generate a connection socket on each incoming connection.
With Accept=yes, your service should be an instance (e.g. foo.socket and foo@.service).  In that case, systemd calls accept() for you and launches your ExecStart= once per connection, passing the FD of the connection socket.  You can read(), select(), poll() from, or write() to that FD immediately.
I tend to use Accept=yes, StandardInput=socket and StandardOutput=socket.   Then I don't need to worry about $LISTEN_FDS, TCP vs UDP.  I just read from stdin and write to stdout.  In that case, anything I want logged is written to stderr which goes to the journal.

If you want to call socket(), bind(), listen() and accept() yourself, then there's no need for a systemd.socket unit.

In terms of your usage...
It usually only makes sense to enable/start the socket.  The socket will take care of starting the service only when data is received.  Your fight with After=, Requires=, Assert*=, and ExecStartPre=mkdir... actually just makes your life harder because you're going against the intended usage.  I would do this:
#rustyvxcan.service
[Unit]
Description=Docker VXCAN plugin Service

# Alternative to PartOf=: Just exit() on EOF (when read() returns 0).
PartOf=rustyvxcan.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/home/braedon/.cargo/bin/rustycan4docker
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

# Note that I deleted the [Install] section of the service
# It will be started by the socket, not by a target.

#rustyvxcan.socket
[Unit]
Description=A network plugin for vxcan
Before=docker.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/docker/plugins/rustyvxcan.sock
RemoveOnStop=True

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

Instead of ExecStartPre=mkdir I would use deploy a tmpfiles.d configuration to ensure systemd generates that path.
# /etc/tmpfiles.d/rustyvxcan.conf
#Type Path                  Mode User Group Age Argument
d     /run/docker/plugins   0755 root root  -   -

systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service will use this file to ensure the directory is created when you boot.  If you want that file to be created now (maybe on installation), then systemd-tmpfiles --create will do it for you.

